# Keep console window open after completion

Tags: batch-file, console

I'm running a bat file and having the output displayed in the console window. Right now, I am having the bat file intentionally fail (bat file contains "STARET www.webaddress.com"). The error catching and everything works, but the console window closes immediately. I would like to keep it open, but so far my searching how to do so hasn't come up with any solutions.

The code I currently have:

```
Me.processStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("C:\Admin\PsTools\psexec.exe", "\\PCName -u domain\" & user & " -p " & pass & " pathtobatfile")
Me.processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
Me.processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
Me.processStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
Me.processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
Dim process As System.Diagnostics.Process = Nothing

'Start the process, which runs the bat file on the remote server
process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Me.processStartInfo)
AddHandler process.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf OutputHandler
process.BeginOutputReadLine()
process.WaitForExit()

Dim errorresponse As DialogResult
   If process.HasExited And process.ExitCode <> 0 Then
      errorresponse = MessageBox.Show("There was an error. Exit code: " & process.ExitCode & _
                        ". Do you wish to view the log?", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        ElseIf process.HasExited And process.ExitCode = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("The update completed successfully.", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        End If
        If errorresponse = DialogResult.Yes Then
          'To fill in later
        End If
```

And the event handler sub:

```
Private Shared Sub OutputHandler(ByVal sendingProcess As Object, ByVal output As DataReceivedEventArgs)
    Console.WriteLine(output.Data)
End Sub
```

I've also tried just doing synchronous output (using StreamReader and Console.Writeline with a Readline()), but that didn't work either.

Comment: Use errorlevel in the bat file.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490920.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add at the end

```
set err=%ERRORLEVEL%
pause
exit %err%
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `pause` at the end of the `BAT` file. Alternatively, if you're lauching the bat file via a `cmd` process, you can add the `/k` argument.

```
cmd /k pathToBatFile
```

Comment: I'm not launching via cmd. It's being launched with Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo). (more detailed in my code above).

Comment: You're launching the bat file via `psexec.exe`. I'm not familiar with that tool, but if it calls `cmd` internally, you could try adding the `/k` argument like this: `& " /k pathtobatfile"`

Comment: Are you able to edit the bat file? Could try adding the word `pause` (without any speech marks) at the end of the file.

Comment: PAUSE sort of works. It does pause and keep the console window open. Problem is then the process always exits successfully so the exit code is always 0 (ie. it never catches errors).